# Why doesn’t a verb’s indirect object have a preposition (like "to") before it?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, indirect-objects, dative-alternation, present-continuous

I don’t understand the grammatical rules behind this sentence:

> It is not showing us the question.

I need to represent it like this:

> It is not showing the question to us.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/show) doesn't have anything like the first version in its examples.

How is this sentence constructed?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Rid. For future reference when you ask next time, please do include at least some rudimentary research in your question. I've added it here for you. You might also be interested in our sister site called [ell.se]. I don't think this question should be migrated there at this stage, because I don't think we have many questions about ditransitivity and this one could be suitable to stay here.

Comment: Your first example is fine and idiomatic. "Us" is indirect object and "the question" is direct object. The structure is like that of "They gave her a book". Note that, as in most though not all ditransitive clauses, you could omit the indirect object but not the direct object. Note also that the VP is in the present progressive aspect.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *It is not showing us the question*.
>
> [2] *It is not showing the question to us*.

The simple answer to your question is that an indirect object can never be the object of a preposition.

In [1] "us" is the indirect object and "the question" is the direct object.

In [2] "the question" is direct object, but "us" is object of the preposition "to", **not** indirect object of the verb. The preposition "to" does of course make a contribution to identifying the semantic recipient: in this case "to us" identifies "us" as the semantic recipient. "To us" is called a non-core complement.

Answer (score 0):

In "You are showing me the question", "me" can be taken as being either

(i) the complement of the verb in the dative grammatical case that implies {**to** + substantive} or {**for** + substantive} and operates as an adverbial prepositional phrase or, and in basic terms,

(ii) an indirect object.

In "You are showing the question **to** me ." the construction is clearer - **to me** is an adverbial prepositional phrase as in "He held the umbrella **over** me", where "He held me the umbrella" would be wrong.

This is known as "the Dative Shift" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift)

Comment: If you ***refuse someone the promotion*** they’d been asking for, you may have a tough time picking a natural-sounding preposition to go with *someone* when reformulating the sentence under dative alternation considering that promotions are neither “denied **to** someone” nor “denied **for** someone”, nor even “denied **with** someone”.

Comment: ... Arguably, similarly with _envy[ing] someone their promotion_. In fact, I've seen this analysed as a double-direct-object construction. As with 'forgive them their trespasses'.

Comment: @tchrist I may be missing something here but, as usual, context is everything: “I refused the promotion to John as he is useless – I promoted Jane.”  “I refused John the promotion as he is useless.” And the verb to deny is often used with to: I denied promotion to John but not Jane / I denied John promotion. *On May 2, an embarrassed Congress **that had continually denied promotion to him**, learned of Arnold’s bravery and finally promoted him to major general.* Oddity Odyssey: A Journey Through New England's Colorful Past By James Chenoweth. Here we see both uses of "to".

Comment: I disagree: in "You are showing me the question", "me" can only be indirect object, nothing else. Note that today's English does not have a dative case. And in "You are showing the question to me", "to me" is not adverbial, but a PP functioning as a non-core complement of "showing".

Comment: @BillJ The dead hand of grammatical cases will never leave English - it explains much of how we got where we are. Novel explanations are novel.